# Gradle failed while building the flutter project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

below is the exception which I have found while building the flutter project (Clone from GitLab).

Launching lib\main.dart on A37fw in debug mode...

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.

error: warnings found and -Werror specified

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':connectivity:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 21m 31s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: You havent attached any image, furthermore dont use images to display error messages include the error as formatted text in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem by downgrade my jdk version to 14 to 11.